# Using Google Analytics Behavior to create funnel

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have an AB test running on Instapage that drives traffic to two different checkout process. The flow of the pages is the following:

Landing Page -> Waiting -> First Checkout Step
Landing Page -> First Checkout Step

According to instapage, the number of users are the same on each variation and the conversion rate (click on CTA that directs to waiting or firstcheckoutstep) are the same as well.

I'm trying to analyze both of them separately using the 'behavior->site content->all pages' in Google Analytics and use the information there to manually build those funnels. To do that, I created two different segments->advanced->conditions:

- Segment 1: Page->Contains 'index' AND'/waiting' (which is the additional page)
- Segment 2: Page->Contains 'index' AND 'first-checkout-page' NOT contains /waiting

They should have the same number of users, however Segment 2 has roughly double of the pageviews than Segment 1.

What could be going wrong?